# Find matrix using its characteristic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, smith-normal-form

so I'm given the following matrix:
$$B=  \left(\begin{matrix}x-1&0&0\\0&(x-1)(x-3)&0\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right) $$
and I'm asked to find a normal form matrix $A$ whose characteristic matrix ($xI_n-A$) is similar to B. I used the rational form and got the matrix :
$$ A= \left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&3\end{matrix}\right) $$
to check my result I calculated the Smith Normal Form of A to compare it with B and I got the matrix: $$ S(A)= \left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&x-1&0\\0&0&(x-1)(x-3)\end{matrix}\right) $$
which is obviously not equivalent to B (compare rank or determinant for example).
Could anyone tell me where the mistake is?

Comment: What is a "normal form matrix"?

Comment: I think the $0$ on the diagonal of $B$ is a typo. Ask your teacher.

Comment: @amsmath the rational form in this case.

Comment: @TedShifrin I found the problem online